# pandas - groupby a column and get the max length of another string column with nulls

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame like this:

```
  source  text_column
0   a      abcdefghi
1   a      abcde
2   b      qwertyiop
3   c      plmnkoijb
4   a      NaN
5   c      abcde
6   b      qwertyiop
7   b      qazxswedcdcvfr
```

and I would like to get the length of `text_column` after grouping `source` column, like below:

```
  source  something
    a        9
    b       14
    c        9
```

Here's what I have tried till now and all of them generate error:

```
>>> # first creating the group by object
>>> text_group = mydf.groupby(by=['source'])
>>> # now try to get the max length of "text_column" by each "source"
>>> text_group['text_column'].map(len).max()
>>> text_group['text_column'].len().max()
>>> text_group['text_column'].str.len().max()
```

How do I get the max length of `text_column` with another column grouped by.

and to avoid creating new question, how do I also get the 2nd biggest length and the respective values(1st and 2nd largest sentences in `text_column`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First idea is use lambda function with [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) and `max`:

```
df = (df.groupby('source')['text_column']
       .agg(lambda x: x.str.len().max())
       .reset_index(name='something'))
print (df)
  source  something
0      a        9.0
1      b       14.0
2      c        9.0
```

Or you can first use [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) and then aggregate `max`:

```
df = (df['text_column'].str.len()
                       .groupby(df['source'])
                       .max()
                       .reset_index(name='something'))
print (df)
```

Also if need integers first use [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df = (df.dropna(subset=['text_column'])
        .assign(text_column=lambda x: x['text_column'].str.len())
        .groupby('source', as_index=False)['text_column']
        .max())
print (df)

  source  text_column
0      a            9
1      b           14
2      c            9
```

EDIT: for first and second top values use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
df1 = (df.dropna(subset=['text_column'])
        .assign(something=lambda x: x['text_column'].str.len())
        .sort_values(['source','something'], ascending=[True, False])
        .groupby('source', as_index=False)
        .head(2))
print (df1)
  source     text_column  something
0      a       abcdefghi          9
1      a           abcde          5
7      b  qazxswedcdcvfr         14
2      b       qwertyiop          9
3      c       plmnkoijb          9
5      c           abcde          5
```

Alternative solution with [`SeriesGroupBy.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html), obviously slowier:

```
df1 = (df.dropna(subset=['text_column'])
         .assign(something=lambda x: x['text_column'].str.len())
         .groupby('source')['something']
         .nlargest(2)
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .reset_index())
print (df1)

  source  something
0      a          9
1      a          5
2      b         14
3      b          9
4      c          9
5      c          5
```

Last solution for new columns by top1, top2:

```
df=df.dropna(subset=['text_column']).assign(something=lambda x: x['text_column'].str.len())

df = df.sort_values(['source','something'], ascending=[True, False])
df['g'] = df.groupby('source').cumcount().add(1)

df = (df[df['g'].le(2)].pivot('source','g','something')
      .add_prefix('top') 
      .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))
print (df)
   top1  top2
a     9     5
b    14     9
c     9     5
```

Comment: I have around 4 million rows and the second approach(Series.str.len and then aggregate max) was fastest. Thanks jezreal.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution to me looks sth like this (tested) -  you do not actually need a groupby:

```
df['str_len'] = df.text_column.str.len()
df.sort_values(['str_len'], ascending=False)\
    .drop_duplicates(['source'])\
    .drop(columns='text_column')

  source  str_len
7      b     14.0
0      a      9.0
3      c      9.0
```

regarding your 2nd question, I think a groupby serves you well:

```
top_x = 2
df.groupby('source', as_index=False)\
    .apply(lambda sourcedf: sourcedf.sort_values('str_len').nlargest(top_x, columns='str_len', keep='all'))\
    .drop(columns='text_column')
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and the answer.

Comment: Changed .head with nlargest in order to avoid cutting off equally long results (as seen in jezrael suggestion)

Answer (score 1):

Just get the lengths first with `assign` and `str.len`:

```
df.assign(text_column=df['text_column'].str.len()).groupby('source', as_index=False).max()
```

---

```
  source  text_column
0      a          9.0
1      b         14.0
2      c          9.0
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and the answer.